# Nested do while loop jump from one to another

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I am having some logic difficulties when trying to use a do-while loop. In my main() method. I am trying to prompt user again and again if they entered anything larger than 6:

```
do{
System.out.println("select your option: ");
        System.out.println("1.option1");
        System.out.println("2.option2");
        System.out.println("3.option3");
        System.out.println("4.option4");
        System.out.println("5.option5");
        System.out.println("6.Quit");
        optionChoice = sc.nextInt();
        switch (optionChoice) {
        case 1:
            option1Method();
            break;
        } 
 } while (optionChoice > 6);
```

Then inside my `option1Method()`, I have another do while loop:

```
    do {
        System.out.println("select your option: ");
        System.out.println("1.opt1 method1");
        System.out.println("2.opt2 method2");
        System.out.println("3.opt3 method3");
        System.out.println("4.Back");
        optOption = sc.nextInt();
        switch (optOption ) {
        case 1: //do stuffs, same for case 2 and 3
           break;
        case 4: return;
        default: break;
       }
} while (optOption > 4);
```

For this method, I am trying to prompt user the choice again and again as long as they entered anything larger than 4. Then, when they entered 4, it should go back to the do while loop in main() method.

However, for the second do-while loop, when I entered 4, the program itself is just terminated. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the second piece of code the body of your `option1Method()`?

Comment: Yes, the second piece belongs to option1Method(). I trying to do like when user enter 4.Back, then it goes back to the first piece of do while which is inside main method

Comment: @I Was So Lost,  does @nuaavee answer solves what you were originally asking. I mean just when the number is greater than 6 the program should continue prompting the user for an option because it will ask the user even if the number is less than 6?

Comment: In addition, could you try what I have suggested `optionChoice > 6 || optionChoice == 1`?

Comment: what about `optOption != 4` as the condition in the second do-while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the main method set the condition as:

```
optionChoice != 6
```

Comment: Because 1 through 5 are not > 6 and your loop will exit. The loop should exit only if equal to 6 according to your option descriptions. You probably meant to write `while (optionChoice < 6);` originally.

Comment: I guess this solves the problem of getting out of the loop, but I am not sure if this solves the problem of keeping in the loop when the number enter by the user is greater than 6.

Comment: @nuaavee Hey sorry I realized that there is still a small problem which is when I successfully execute the method from case 1 in second piece of do while loop right, it straight away jump back to first piece of do while. Is there any other way to keep it around the second piece of do while until user entered 4.Back then go back to first piece?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but I have written the following for you:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Answer {
  static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  static int optionChoice;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    do{
      System.out.println("select your option: ");
      System.out.println("1.option1");
      System.out.println("2.option2");
      System.out.println("3.option3");
      System.out.println("4.option4");
      System.out.println("5.option5");
      System.out.println("6.Quit");
      optionChoice = sc.nextInt();

      switch (optionChoice) {
        case 1:
            option1Method();
          break;
      }
    } while (optionChoice > 6);
  }

  public static void option1Method() {

    int optOption;

    do {
       System.out.println("select your option: ");
       System.out.println("1.opt1 method1");
       System.out.println("2.opt2 method2");
       System.out.println("3.opt3 method3");
       System.out.println("4.Back");
       optOption = sc.nextInt();
       switch (optOption ) {
       case 1: //do stuffs, same for case 2 and 3
          break;
       case 4:
        optionChoice = 7; // you have to make this value greater than 6 if you want to continue in the loop
        return;
       default: break;
      }
    } while (optOption > 4);
  }
}
```

The problem when you enter 4 is that you go back to the main method, and the value you entered for `optionChoice` is 1 which makes `false` the condition of the while loop.

**EDIT:**

In response to @Timeout who is totally right by claiming I am assuming that optionChoice is a "global variable".

To keep your functionality I guess you should just have the following condition in the do-while loop of the main() method:

```
optionChoice > 6 || optionChoice == 1
```

**EDIT:**

what if you add as a condition in the second while loop

```
optOption != 4
```

so that you will remain in that loop until the user enters 4

**EDIT TO HANDLE optionXMethod where X is a number:**

```
do{
      System.out.println("select your option: ");
      System.out.println("1.option1");
      System.out.println("2.option2");
      System.out.println("3.option3");
      System.out.println("4.option4");
      System.out.println("5.option5");
      System.out.println("6.Quit")
      optionChoice = sc.nextInt();

      switch (optionChoice) {
        case 1:
            option1Method();
            break;
        case 2:
            option2Method();
            break;
        case X:
            optionXMethod();
          break;
      }
    } while (optionChoice != 6);

void option1Method() {
    int optOption;

    do {
       System.out.println("select your option: ");
       System.out.println("1.opt1 method1");
       System.out.println("2.opt2 method2");
       System.out.println("3.opt3 method3");
       System.out.println("4.Back");
       optOption = sc.nextInt();
       switch (optOption ) {
       case 1: //do stuffs, same for case 2 and 3
          break;
// you do not need the case 4: because when optOptiontakes the value of 4 it leaves the loop

   default: break;
  }
} while (optOption != 4);
```

}

....

General case:

```
void optionXMethod() {
    int optOption;

    do {
       System.out.println("select your option: ");
       System.out.println("1.opt1 method1");
       System.out.println("2.opt2 method2");
       System.out.println("3.opt3 method3");
       System.out.println("4.opt4 method4");
       // more options
       System.out.println("X.Back"); // where X is the number option of Back
       optOption = sc.nextInt();
       switch (optOption ) {
       case 1: //do stuffs, same for case 2 and 3
          break;
// you do not need the case 4: because when optOptiontakes the value of 4 it leaves the loop

   default: break;
  }
} while (optOption != X); // whatever the value of X is should be consider for this condition
```

}

Comment: Let me know if this is the behavior you expect to have, or if you can add any further explanation so that I can improve my answer. I have run this answer, and when the user enter first a number greater than 6 it prompts the user again and again. If he chooses 1 `option1Method()` runs, and if the user enters a number greater than 4 it prompts the user again and again.

Comment: @Timeout, I have edited my answer, and I think that in this case it solves what @I Was So Lost wanted to do initially.

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf Hmm but when user successfully execute the case from second piece of code, the program itself just terminated.

Comment: @IWasSoLost, I guess that the last edit I have added solves your problem

Comment: Sorry but let's say my second do while loop contain 9 choices and the 9.Back. So in my case 9, I should do like this: optionChoice = 10;return; and the while (optOption != 9); Am I correct?

Comment: by optionChoice = 10 you mean case: 10? I guess you should not include the case 10 because in the end if the user enters a number that is greater than 9 this is going to prompt it for another option if you condition is `optOption != 9`

Comment: I mean what value should I assign to optionChoice in the case 9 if my case 9 from the second do while loop is back to the first do while loop

Comment: is `optionChoice` a "global variable"? if so, yes you should give it the value of 10, but if this is not a "global variable" you could simply `case 9: return;` and your do-while condition should be `optOption != 9`

Comment: yeah but strangely it only works for the option1Method() calling from first do while. I added option2Method() for thefirst do while, and inside option2Method() I got 9 choices, I did the same thing but somehow when I entered 9.Back, the program just terminated without  going back to the first do while. But when I sucessfully executed other cases in option2Method(), it did still going back to the second do while

Comment: Your `option2Method()` is calleld in `case 2:` of the do-while of the main() method?

Comment: Yeah, exactly same as case 1.Just that it is under case 2 and different method name. Ah I figured out already, it should be optionChoice != 6. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106777/discussion-between-lmiguelvargasf-and-i-was-so-lost).

Comment: @IWasSoLost, could you please check after EDIT TO HANDLE optionXMethod where X is a number, to see if this solves your problem?